# Binary predictor associated with high and low values of a dependent variable

Tags: regression, binary-data, predictor

What approach should I use to incorporate a binary predictor variable in a regression model in the following situation?

- When the binary predictor takes the value 1 then the dependent variable tends to take very high or very low values.
- When the binary predictor takes the value 0 then the dependent variable tends to take values close to the mean.

The binary variable clearly contains useful predictive value, but how can I exploit this in a regression model?

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if you could center your response and then take the absolute value. Essentially then, you could see if your binary predictor does actually predict "distance from the mean". I've never seen this before, though, so I'm not confident in the response. Interesting question, though.

Comment: Well.. which "regression model" are you using? [Linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)? Or (something like) a [Random Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest)? The latter should have no problem with this kind of behavior.

Comment: I was planning to use a generalised linear model.  Can this approach handle the behaviour I describe or do I need to consider an alternative approach?

Comment: Thanks dankernler.  I can see how this would work, but not sure how useful the outputs would be.  The model would tell me how far the predicted value was from the mean, but not the direction.